# How onclick can post to a new page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

How may I have a tag `<a>` to `onclick` go to a new page and `POST` something?

I have the code below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="cat_filter(1);">Cat Name</a>
```

And the function `cat_filter()`

```
function cat_filter(cat) {

    jQuery.ajax({
      'url': 'http://xxx/procurar', 
      'type': 'POST',
      'dataType': 'json', 
      'data': {cat: cat}
    });

}
```

PHP on URL page

```
$cat = $_POST['cat´];
```

What I neeed to do is to execute the `function cat_filter()` to pass the variable to a new `URL` as `POST`. How may I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [navigate to another page with post request through link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378619/navigate-to-another-page-with-post-request-through-link)

Comment: @Terminus, thanks you for the suggestion, but the question you marked as possible duplicate is not passing a `POST` to the new page.

Comment: Well sure the question isn't but the answer is ;) I like @gibberish's answer more than the accepted one over there anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is a methodology for sending data to another PHP file *without navigating away from the current page.*

If you wish to send the data and also navigate over to the new page, you can do this:

```js
function cat_filter(cat) {
  var myform = '<form id="ff" action="procurar" method="post">\
    <input name="cat" value="' +cat+ '" />\
    </form>';
  $('body').append(myform);
  $('#ff').submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="cat_filter(1);">Cat Name</a>
```