# Change get to post

Tags: javascript, html, post

Currently I have this url to send data to another page.

```
function clickBtn(){
    window.location.href =`/dashboard?id=12&name=test
}
```

Now I want to send this by post.

However it is said `window.location.href` is impossible to use for `post`

So I made this `form` however it is not javascript and also require user to click submit button.

```
<form action=dashbaord>
<input type=hidden id=id value=12>
<input type=hidden id=name value="test">
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Is there any more equivalent way to the `window.location.href`?

Comment: have you not heard of ajax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Why do you want to use JavaScript? Your HTML code has very similar behavior. You click on submit and your location is changed. It's like  before but now it's a POST request.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone How do you use AJAX to navigate to a new URL as POST request? OP asks _"Is there any more equivalent way to the `window.location.href`?"_

Comment: @Ivar How can you use XMLHttpRequest to navigate to a new URL as POST request? OP asks _"Is there any more equivalent way to the `window.location.href`?"_

Comment: @jabaa fair point, ok the OP could use the bubbled click event and build out the form and submit it, dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003089/dynamically-create-and-submit-form

Comment: @jabaa It's not obvious to me at all that it is a requirement to navigate to the other page. All I know is that they "_have this url to send data to another page_". If this doesn't answer the question, it is up to OP to clarify it in their question why it doesn't.

Comment: @Ivar _"Is there any more equivalent way to the `window.location.href`?"_ is pretty clear for me. Try it in your browser console. It will always navigate.

Comment: Equivalent in what way @jabaa? That you can send data from one page to another? Because that's also possible with AJAX. The equivalent of `window.location.href` would also send a GET request which is obviously not what OP wants. You'd be surprise how often [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)-questions are asked.

Comment: @Ivar OP want's equivalent behavior to `window.location.href =\`/dashboard?id=12&name=test\`` but it should be a POST request. `dashboard` is probably a path on the site that contains a dashboard for a user with `id` and `name`. OP probably doesn't want the credentials in the URL. The use-case and the requirements are pretty clear. AJAX won't help here.

Comment: @jabaa I see your point, but am not convinced that is actually what OP is after. As I read it, their goal is to send data from one page to another, and they _attempted_ to use `window.location.href` due to lack of an alternative. Read the link in my previous question about XY-Problems. It's a common phenomenon here at Stack Overflow. You _might_ be right. But in that case OP should clarify it in their question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [navigate to another page with post request through link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378619/navigate-to-another-page-with-post-request-through-link)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form via JavaScript, append `input` fields on it  and then post it which will change window location as well. Give it a try:

```
function PostForm(PostTo, DataParams) {

  const Form = document.createElement('form');
  Form.action = PostTo;
  Form.method = "post";

  for (const Param in DataParams) {

      const HiddenField = document.createElement('input');
      HiddenField.type = 'hidden';
      HiddenField.name = Param;
      HiddenField.value = DataParams[Param];
      Form.appendChild(HiddenField); //append to form  
  }

  document.body.appendChild(Form);
  Form.submit();
}
```

Then Use it like:

```
function clickBtn(){
    PostForm('/dashboard/', {name: 'test', id: '12'});
}
```